# CSS Container fit to Child-Images

Tags: html, css

First: I really tried to find an answer but non of them worked for me.
Here's my problem:

I have a base layout where I have a forward and a backward button in the footer.
Theses buttons must be quadratic. So I've decided to make them simple images (*to avoid all the problems with trying to scaling divs propotionally*).

Theses images have CSS:

```
.galleryFooterController {
    position: relative;
    
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
    
    background-color: #A0A0A0;
}
```

And are nested in a container with CSS:

```
#galleryFooterControlle {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    right: 15%;
    background: white;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 5px;
    
    width: auto;
}
```

But the container is not taking the correct width so that the images are not fitting inside and are rendered under each other. If I take out the height: 100% from the images, they fit next to each other in the container.

[image]

It would be great if you could help me finding a JS-free version to solve this problem!
Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us a http://www.jsfiddle.com/?

Comment: And what is a 'quadratic button'?

Comment: Its just a quadratic image im using as a button

Comment: "square" I guess, no?

Comment: right. I'm not english. Quadratic doesn't work to say something should be a square?

Comment: hahah nope. Quadratic does refer to squares, but usually in the context of formulas, like for example y = x^2 is a quadratic equation, because x is squared (to the power of two).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sYck7/1/) that will give you a start.

I haven't made all of the divs line-up, but you can change the CSS to make it look prettier.

For your buttons, I just used div in a div with CSS-Tricks triangle - You can use .click on the outer div to run your function.

Here's the relevant CSS

```
.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #A0A0A0;
  border: 4px solid white;
}
.container {
  width: 90%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #A0A0A0;
  border: 4px solid white;
  float: left;
}
.rightbar {
  width: 9%;
  height: 460px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  float: right;
  background-color: #A0A0A0;    
}
.bottomholder {
  width: 90%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.bottomleft {
  height: 100%;
  width: 562px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #A0A0A0;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
}
.bottombutton {
  height: 100%;
  width: 130px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #A0A0A0;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
}
.bottomright {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #A0A0A0;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
}
.arrowleft {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid white;
  background-color: #A0A0A0;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.arrow-left {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 15px solid black;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.arrowright {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid white;
  background-color: #A0A0A0;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.arrow-right {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid black;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the efoort! But if i would use fixed values for width and height, then i wouldn't have the problem that the container is too small. I could simply make it bigger!
I'll update my question with more information!

Comment: @Martin then set .bottomholder {height: auto;}

Answer (score 0):

Just i tried with liquid layout, removed the border 2px white and change the float property.

```
.header {
        width: 98%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #A0A0A0;
        margin:2px 2px;
        }
.container{
        width: 85%;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: #A0A0A0;
        margin:2px 2px;
        float: left;
        }
.rightbar{
       width: 12%;
       height: 460px;
       float: left;
       background-color: #A0A0A0;
       margin-top:2px;
       margin-left: 2px;
      padding-left: 3px;
          }
```

Full Code http://jsfiddle.net/judearasu/5c5rq/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone I figguered out how to solve the problem!
Because the images coudn't be rendered next to each other because its container would't pick the right width after scaling the images, i simply made the container width to the maximum available place which was in my project 85%. So now the images are fitting in!

Thanks again!